# How to implement sticky Menu according to my Theme?

Tags: jquery, ajax, menubar

Its been long time, i am searching for a good code or a plugin either from scratch or ready made. I need to know how can i implement a sticky menu for my site. my site is [ExamsInformer](http://examsinformer.com).

Which plugin will help me to build a good sticky menu bar which will suit my theme. If there isn't any plugin then how can i proceed with Jquery setup of Menu with sticky Menu.

Sticky in the sense it should float below the URL screen whenever i scroll down. I am a beginer in php, java. and know little bit coding for css.

How can i proceed with it? Could anyone help me out.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve.

What I recommend:

- Utilize the WP embedded menu options as much as possible. (You should be able to find them here: http://examsinformer.com/wp-admin/nav-menus.php )
- If you're looking to code your own menu, [utilize a child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes). You can make one based upon the one you are currently using. If the theme or framework gets updated, your customized code doesn't get lost in the update.

Comment: Hi Jay, I am looking for a Menu bar which is quite similar to this website http://placementadda.com  and which also suits my website theme. I don't mind building up a new menu bar which is exactly similar to the above link i have provided. But my question is how??